# Apache Jmeter HTTPRequest is not responding?

Tags: apache, jmeter, httprequest, jmeter-plugins

I have a Problem with Apache Jmeter's HTTPRequest.

For a URL like:

```
http://vast.bp3858435.btrll.com/vast/3858435?n=1421841861&br_w=[]
```

It works and responds normally.

But when I add % sign to my URL it doesn't respond in Jmeter and it returns the following:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Malformed escape pair at index 141: http://vast.bp3858435.btrll.com/vast/3858435?n=1421841861&br_w=[]%
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.scanEscape(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.scan(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:252)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `%` by itself is an escape character, and by itself is not a valid character in a URI. There are certain characters that are invalid for any URI (including the `%` character itself) and must be encoded using a `%` symbol followed by a two digit hexadecimal number.

If you want to send the percent (`%`) symbol by itself as part of the URI data, it is encoded as `%25`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

You can use [`URLEncoder.encode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) to encode a URI/URL. JMeter also has [its own encode function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) as of version 2.0 (`__urlencode()`)

Comment: Yes, That's completely right, but how can I encode the URL automatically inside jmeter?